# How to create dynamic lists from a json in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

I am retrieving data with the following structure from a REST API

```
job_execs = 
[{
    "build_id": 12,
    "job": {
      "name": "test_job"
    },
    "product": {
      "name": "new_product"
    },
    "time_start": "2017-08-29T01:01:19.314000-07:00",
    "time_end": "2017-08-29T01:17:07.990000-07:00",
    "status": {
      "name": "SUCCESS"
    },
    "stage_executions": [{
        "stage": {
          "name": "stage-checkout"
        },
        "status": {
          "name": "SUCCESS"
        },
        "duration_millis": 119,
        "time_start": "2017-08-29T01:16:43.901000-07:00"
      },
      {
        "stage": {
          "name": "stage-wiki"
        },
        "status": {
          "name": "SUCCESS"
        },
        "duration_millis": 14225,
        "time_start": "2017-08-29T01:16:29.599000-07:00"
      },
      {
        "stage": {
          "name": "stage-upload"
        },
        "status": {
          "name": "SUCCESS"
        },
        "duration_millis": 14225,
        "time_start": "2017-08-29T01:16:29.599000-07:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "build_id": 13,
    "job": {
      "name": "test_job"
    },
    "product": {
      "name": "new_product"
    },
    "time_start": "2017-08-29T01:01:19.314000-07:00",
    "time_end": "2017-08-29T01:17:07.990000-07:00",
    "status": {
      "name": "SUCCESS"
    },
    "stage_executions": [{
        "stage": {
          "name": "stage-checkout"
        },
        "status": {
          "name": "SUCCESS"
        },
        "duration_millis": 400,
        "time_start": "2017-08-29T01:16:43.901000-07:00"
      },
      {
        "stage": {
          "name": "stage-wiki"
        },
        "status": {
          "name": "SUCCESS"
        },
        "duration_millis": 34,
        "time_start": "2017-08-29T01:16:29.599000-07:00"
      },
      {
        "stage": {
          "name": "stage-upload"
        },
        "status": {
          "name": "SUCCESS"
        },
        "duration_millis": 250,
        "time_start": "2017-08-29T01:16:29.599000-07:00"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is drill into the stage executions per job and generate a list per stage name.  I want to loop through every job and append the duration_millis to the appropriate stage list.

So taking the JSON I posted above, I would want the following lists created:

```
['stage_checkout', 119, 400]
['stage_wiki', 14225, 34]
['stage_upload', 1215, 250]
```

How do I accomplish this?

Any pointers or even a starting point would help.

Comment: you can use a `for` loop (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) to go through every job and extract the data you need for each one appending it to the new list you are creating. Try something and show the code if you still can't get it to work ;)

Comment: the json here is invalid, are you sure this is the correct json?

Comment: some brackets are missing and json is invalid

Comment: the json I'm working with is valid, this is a typo, I just fixed

Comment: still not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This might work, I have broken it down to simple functions so you can understand what is happening here.**

```js
var job_execs = 
[{
    "build_id": 12,
    "job": {
      "name": "test_job"
    },
    "product": {
      "name": "new_product"
    },
    "time_start": "2017-08-29T01:01:19.314000-07:00",
    "time_end": "2017-08-29T01:17:07.990000-07:00",
    "status": {
      "name": "SUCCESS"
    },
    "stage_executions": [{
        "stage": {
          "name": "stage-checkout"
        },
        "status": {
          "name": "SUCCESS"
        },
        "duration_millis": 119,
        "time_start": "2017-08-29T01:16:43.901000-07:00"
      },
      {
        "stage": {
          "name": "stage-wiki"
        },
        "status": {
          "name": "SUCCESS"
        },
        "duration_millis": 14225,
        "time_start": "2017-08-29T01:16:29.599000-07:00"
      },
      {
        "stage": {
          "name": "stage-upload"
        },
        "status": {
          "name": "SUCCESS"
        },
        "duration_millis": 14225,
        "time_start": "2017-08-29T01:16:29.599000-07:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "build_id": 13,
    "job": {
      "name": "test_job"
    },
    "product": {
      "name": "new_product"
    },
    "time_start": "2017-08-29T01:01:19.314000-07:00",
    "time_end": "2017-08-29T01:17:07.990000-07:00",
    "status": {
      "name": "SUCCESS"
    },
    "stage_executions": [{
        "stage": {
          "name": "stage-checkout"
        },
        "status": {
          "name": "SUCCESS"
        },
        "duration_millis": 400,
        "time_start": "2017-08-29T01:16:43.901000-07:00"
      },
      {
        "stage": {
          "name": "stage-wiki"
        },
        "status": {
          "name": "SUCCESS"
        },
        "duration_millis": 34,
        "time_start": "2017-08-29T01:16:29.599000-07:00"
      },
      {
        "stage": {
          "name": "stage-upload"
        },
        "status": {
          "name": "SUCCESS"
        },
        "duration_millis": 250,
        "time_start": "2017-08-29T01:16:29.599000-07:00"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const func = (arr) => {
  var ch = {};
  arr.map(ar => {
         ar.stage_executions.map((s) => {
        ch[s.stage.name] = [];
      })
  })
  return ch;
}

const func2 = (arr) => {
  var all = func(arr);
  for(var k in all) {
    arr.map((ar) => {
      ar.stage_executions.map((st) => {
        if (st.stage.name === k) {
          all[k].push(st.stage.name, st.duration_millis)
        }
      })
    })
  }
  return all;
}

const func3 = (arr) => {
  const all = func2(arr);
  for(var key in all) {
    all[key] = [...new Set(all[key])]
  }
  return all;
}

console.log(func3(job_execs))
```

Comment: Can you summarize what these three functions are doing?  I cannot follow what's happening.

Comment: The first function is looping through the array and again looping through the `stage_execution` and storing all the names in an object, this will ensure we only have unique names since objects cannot have duplicates. In the second function, we are just simply creating a new object with key as the stage name and pushing all the required properties into the array. The third function is just removing all the duplicates from the resultant array,

Answer (score 0):

This code sample might help you. As well i changed the invalid JSON to a valid one and hope this is still matching your data basis.

```js
job_execs = [{"build_id":12,"job":{"name":"test_job"},"product":{"name":"new_product"},"time_start":"2017-08-29T01:01:19.314000-07:00","time_end":"2017-08-29T01:17:07.990000-07:00","status":{"name":"SUCCESS"},"stage_executions":[{"stage":{"name":"stage-checkout"},"status":{"name":"SUCCESS"},"duration_millis":119,"time_start":"2017-08-29T01:16:43.901000-07:00"},{"stage":{"name":"stage-wiki"},"status":{"name":"SUCCESS"},"duration_millis":14225,"time_start":"2017-08-29T01:16:29.599000-07:00"},{"stage":{"name":"stage-upload"},"status":{"name":"SUCCESS"},"duration_millis":14225,"time_start":"2017-08-29T01:16:29.599000-07:00"}]},{"build_id":13,"job":{"name":"test_job"},"product":{"name":"new_product"},"time_start":"2017-08-29T01:01:19.314000-07:00","time_end":"2017-08-29T01:17:07.990000-07:00","status":{"name":"SUCCESS"},"stage_executions":[{"stage":{"name":"stage-checkout"},"status":{"name":"SUCCESS"},"duration_millis":400,"time_start":"2017-08-29T01:16:43.901000-07:00"},{"stage":{"name":"stage-wiki"},"status":{"name":"SUCCESS"},"duration_millis":34,"time_start":"2017-08-29T01:16:29.599000-07:00"},{"stage":{"name":"stage-upload"},"status":{"name":"SUCCESS"},"duration_millis":250,"time_start":"2017-08-29T01:16:29.599000-07:00"}]}]
var aCheckout = ['stage-checkout'];
var aWiki = ['stage-wiki'];
var aUpload = ['stage-upload'];

job_execs.forEach(function (build) {
  build.stage_executions.forEach(function (stage) {
 switch(stage.stage.name){
  case "stage-checkout": 
      aCheckout.push(stage.duration_millis);
   break;
  case "stage-wiki": 
   aWiki.push(stage.duration_millis);
   break;
  case "stage-upload": 
   aUpload.push(stage.duration_millis);
   break;
    }
  });
})
console.log(aCheckout, aWiki, aUpload);
```